# How to connect to a specific database within a SQL Server instance?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, python-2.7, pymssql, dentrix

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2
SQLAlchemy==1.0.9

I'm trying to use SQLAlchemy to connect to and READ an existing Microsoft SQL database. The MSSQL has multiple instances, with multiple databases within each instance ...

[image: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio]

The issue is, I can connect using the instance name, but not a database name.

So, two questions:

1. Can I connect using JUST a database name?
2. If not, how do I switch the engine/session to a specific database?

To connect I have been using ...

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://sa:<pass>@Servername\Instance')
```

...which connects it to the default 'Master' database and I can read the tables fine using...

```
inspector = inspect(engine)
for table_name in inspector.get_table_names():
    print '======='
    print ('TABLE: %s' % table_name) 
    for column in inspector.get_columns(table_name):
        print("Column: %s" % column['name'])
```

---UPDATE---

So, made a little progress.

I discovered that you can get a list of tables and columns from inspector, if you first run a 'USE Database' command.

However, this doesn't actually help when it comes to using SQLAlchemy objects with an MS SQL Server connection where you've had to connect to an instance instead of directly to a database. I.e.

```
inspector = inspect(connection)
connection.execute('USE Dentrix')

for table_name in inspector.get_table_names():
    print '======='
    print ('TABLE: %s' % table_name) 
    for column in inspector.get_columns(table_name):
        print("Column: %s" % column['name'])
```

...outputs the correct data...

```
(snip)
=======
TABLE: AUDIT_PRINT_USER_BASE
Column: RequestID
Column: RequestDB
Column: ReportName
Column: USER_CHANGED
Column: DATE_CHANGED
=======
TABLE: CONV_ID
Column: CONVID
Column: Conv_Tech
=======
(snip)
```

However, when I try to use the SQLAlchemy syntax, even after using 'USE Database' first, I get errors...

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://sa:<pass>@Servername\Instance')
connection = engine.connect()
metadata = MetaData(engine)
print 'metadata=', metadata

# engine.echo = True
connection.execute('USE Dentrix')
# CONV_ID = Table('CONV_ID', metadata, autoload=True)             # ALL CREATE THE SAME ERROR
# CONV_ID = Table('Dentrix.CONV_ID', metadata, autoload=True)     # ALL CREATE THE SAME ERROR
# CONV_ID = Table('dbo.CONV_ID', metadata, autoload=True)         # ALL CREATE THE SAME ERROR
CONV_ID = Table('Dentrix.dbo.CONV_ID', metadata, autoload=True)   # ALL CREATE THE SAME ERROR
```

...these all return the same basic error...

```
start...
metadata= MetaData(bind=Engine(mssql+pymssql://sa:***@Servername\Instance))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mikes/Documents/Eclipseworkspace/Telemend/Telemend-Dentrix-Reporting/test/ormtest.py", line 36, in <module>
    CONV_ID = Table('Dentrix.dbo.CONV_ID', metadata, autoload=True) 
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 416, in __new__
    metadata._remove_table(name, schema)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 60, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 411, in __new__
    table._init(name, metadata, *args, **kw)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 484, in _init
    self._autoload(metadata, autoload_with, include_columns)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 508, in _autoload
    self, include_columns, exclude_columns
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1972, in run_callable
    return conn.run_callable(callable_, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1477, in run_callable
    return callable_(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 364, in reflecttable
    return insp.reflecttable(table, include_columns, exclude_columns)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py", line 571, in reflecttable
    raise exc.NoSuchTableError(table.name)
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchTableError: Dentrix.dbo.CONV_ID
```

Comment: The example URL for mssql+pymssql example [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/engines.html#microsoft-sql-server) shows the "dbname" preceded by a forward slash (`/`), not a backslash. Did you try that?

Comment: Hi Gord. Thanks for the comment. I did actually. The URL format allows for only one forward slash after server:port. Because the hierarchy for MSSQL is EITHER server:database, or server:instance:database...if I try (on a server with separate instances) server:port/database, it fails because it doesn't know which instance (or tries the default instance, which doesn't work in this case). If server:port/instance, it connects to the instance, but stays at the 'master' DB level. If server:port/instance/database....it gives an error.

Comment: *"if I try (on a server with separate instances) server:port/database, it fails because it doesn't know which instance"* - Really? That's odd, because each instance listens on a different port, so `server:port` in fact *does* refer to a particular instance: the only instance listening on that port.

Comment: Hi Gord. I discovered that as well, and I'm looking into that. I'm not sure if it's the default for ALL MSSQL servers, or just the one I'm working on (I did not set it up)...but in the 'SQL Server Network Configuration | Protocols for (instance) | TCP/IP'...'TCP dynamic ports' is set to 0, and 'TCP Port' is blank, which means the port are dynamically controlled (and it seems, you connect via 1433 and specify instance). In order to set (at least this particular) MSSQL server to associate an 'instance=port_num' I have to change this configuration. I'm currently seeking permissions to do that :)

Comment: I understand this from : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177440.aspx. If I'm incorrect, please let me know. I'm fairly new to MSSQL....also...if you look at my original question, you'll notice I dont actually specify the port. Just server/instance. Part of the reason I do this is, with the exception of the info in the link included in this post, I don't know where I would find what port is tied to what instance. Is there another place to find what port or way to set an instance to port?

Comment: [This](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/portoverride.htm) seems to suggest that `r'mssql+pymssql://sa:<pass>@Servername\Instance'` should work. If not, then maybe a [freetds.conf](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/freetdsconf.htm) file might help.

Comment: I may look into a freetds.conf file...as well as changing the server config. It would be better if I didn't have to change the server config. ... For clarity: 'conn = mssql+pymssql://sa:<pass>@Servername\Instance' does indeed work...but connects only to the instance, and there seems to be no way (aside from configuring the port on the server, or a freetds.conf file) to tell 'conn' which of the 7 databases living under 'instance' it should be talking to...without using direct SQL statements, instead of the ORM objects.

Comment: Ah, okay, I get it now. Hence your comment about being able to specify instance or database but not both. BTW, are you running your SQLAlchemy stuff on a Windows machine or a non-Windows machine?

Comment: I'm currently running on OSX...but will be migrating to a windows 2008R3